# Change cursor for drag and drop to nonDragZone or DraggableZone in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have to change cursor icon whenever dragging an item  to  nondraggable and draggable zone.How can i achieve this in angular.
so first i have tried  to set  predefined cursor "grabbing" while dragging but still not able to set.

The default looks like in the screenshot (pointer with a small rectangle below), but I need to change that to a custom image or grabbing

[image]

Here is the code link 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-wsyygt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

> CodeSnippet:

```
 <div>
   <div class="drag1" *ngFor="let vehicle of canBeCopy" draggable="true"  (dragstart)="onDragStart(vehicle,$event)" >
      <p>{{vehicle}}</p>
   </div>
</div>

<hr>
<div>
  <p>Drop Area</p>
<div class="availablevehicle" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)"(drop)="onDrop($event)">
   <div *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles" >
      <p>{{vehicle}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
```

> .ts file

```
onDrop(ev) {
    let index = this.vehicles.findIndex((v)=>v==this.vehicle);
     if(index<0){
         this.vehicles.push(this.vehicle);
     }
     ev.target.style.cursor = "pointer"

  }
onDragStart(vehicle,event){
   this.vehicle = vehicle;
   event.target.style.cursor = "grabbing"
   console.log("vent",event);

}
  allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
     ev.target.style.cursor = "grabbing"

    ev.preventDefault();
  }
```

any code snippet solution appreciable

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but check out adding HostBinding/HostListener to a directive.

in a directive, you can create a HostBinding:

```
@HostBinding('style.cursor') private cursor = 'default';
```

Then you can target dragover events via a HostListener

```
@HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) onDragOver(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.cursor = 'pointer' // any custom cursor would be assigned here
}
```

Here's a good reference https://alligator.io/angular/hostbinding-hostlistener/

Happy Coding!

Comment: Hi Thanks for replay,i have tried as you suggest ,but still i am not able to change cursor  while dragging to the dragabbleZone. 
Here is the link  https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-wtigxg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fondrag.directive.ts

Answer (score 0):

i think allowDrop($event) is the issue may be you don't need that instead use other mousedrag handlers